# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contato has no column named

Tags: java, android, sql, database

this is my error in cosole:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contato has
>   no column named cpf (code 1): , while compiling: insert into contato
>   (nome, cpf, idade, telefone, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

This is my DBhelper script:

```js
package bonato.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Bonato on 29/06/2017.
 */
public class DBHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bancodedados.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contato";

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private SQLiteStatement insertStnt;
    private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (nome, cpf, idade, telefone, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.insertStnt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);

    }

    // OBJETIVO.......:Ordem nas colunas
    public long insert(String nome, String cpf, String idade, String telefone, String email) {
        this.insertStnt.bindString(1, nome);
        this.insertStnt.bindString(2, cpf);
        this.insertStnt.bindString(3, idade);
        this.insertStnt.bindString(4, telefone);
        this.insertStnt.bindString(5, email);

        return this.insertStnt.executeInsert();
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }


    // OBJETIVO.......: Tratar exceções
    public List<Contato> queryGetAll() {
        List<Contato> list = new ArrayList<Contato>();
        // OBJETIVO.......: Retornar uma lista de objetos contato
        try {
            Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"nome", "cpf", "idade", "telefone", "email"},
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);
            int nregistros = cursor.getCount();
            if (nregistros != 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    Contato contato = new Contato(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
                    list.add(contato);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                    cursor.close();
                return list;

            } else
                return null;

        } catch (Exception erro) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, nome TEXT, cpf TEXT, idade TEXT, telefone TEXT, email TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }
}
```

```js
package bonato.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by Bonato on 29/06/2017.
 */
public class Contato {

    // OBJETIVO.......: Atributos

    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String idade;
    private String telefone;
    private String email;


    // OBJETIVO.......: Construtor

    public Contato(String nome, String cpf, String idade, String telefone, String email) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.email = email;

    }

    // OBJETIVO.......: Informacoes

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(String idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

```js
package bonato.myapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.List;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // OBJETIVO.......: Ao clicar no botao voltara para a tela inicial e inserir dados no banco de dados

    private DBHelper dh;
    EditText etNome, etCpf, etIdade, etTelefone, etEmail;
    Button btInserir, btListar;


    Button btVoltar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        this.dh = new DBHelper(this);
        etNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnome);
        etCpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcpf);
        etIdade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etidade);
        etTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettelefone);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);

        btInserir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btinserir);
        btListar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlistar);

        // OBJETIVO.......: Metodo que vai inserir no banco de dados
        btInserir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etNome.getText().length()>0 && etCpf.getText().length()>0 && etIdade.getText().length()>0 && etTelefone.getText().length()>0 && etEmail.getText().length()>0){
                    dh.insert(etNome.getText().toString(),etCpf.getText().toString(), etIdade.getText().toString(), etTelefone.getText().toString(),etEmail.getText().toString());
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Sucesso!");
                    adb.setMessage("Cadastro Realizado!");
                    adb.show();

                    etNome.setText("");
                    etCpf.setText("");
                    etIdade.setText("");
                    etTelefone.setText("");
                    etEmail.setText("");
                }else{

                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Erro!");
                    adb.setMessage("Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos!");
                    adb.show();

                    etNome.setText("");
                    etCpf.setText("");
                    etIdade.setText("");
                    etTelefone.setText("");
                    etEmail.setText("");


                }

            }
        });
        // OBJETIVO.......: MOSTRA SE EXISTEM REGISTROS OU NAO, SE HOUVER DEVE LISTA-LOS
        btListar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<Contato> contatos = dh.queryGetAll();
                if (contatos == null){
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Mensagem");
                    adb.setMessage("Nao ha registros cadastrados!");
                    adb.show();
                    return;
                }
                for (int i =0; i<contatos.size(); i++){
                    Contato contato = (Contato) contatos.get(i);
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Registro" + i);
                    adb.setMessage("Nome: " +contato.getNome()+"\nCPF: " + contato.getCpf()+"\nIdade: " + contato.getIdade()+"\nTelefone: " +contato.getTelefone()+"\nE-mail: "+contato.getEmail());
                    adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    adb.show();

                }
            }
        });

        btVoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btVoltar);
        btVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                voltarParaPrimeiraTela();
            }
        });
    }

    void voltarParaPrimeiraTela(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

I need help finding the error, I have no idea what it can be, because the "cpf" is already there.

Comment: Show the script which creates the table

Comment: What is the DB structure?

Comment: Ready, edit the post with more information, I'm still learning, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

No, "cpf" is not already there.  There is no field called "cpf" in the table "contato" in database "bancodedados.db".

That's because the `onUpgrade()` method is not invoked, so the table is never dropped and never re-created, so you have some old version of the table which does not contain a "cpf" field.

If you believe it does, then prove it.

Comment: Thank you! I deleted all existing dbs and restarted the application, now it worked perfectly!